# Deploying multiple Azure API App Versioning

Tags: azure-api-apps

I have a requirement to deploy multiple version of the same API app where the client older application use the existing and the new clients use the new api app which is got more functionality.

Is there a way to achieve this with Azure API Apps?

Answer (score 0):

I have an article that shows how to do [Transparent Versioning](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/api-management-sample-cache-by-key/#transparent-versioning) using API Management in front of API Apps.

The basic idea is that you have a version parameter in a URL and then use the `set-backend-service` to change which version of the API to access.

Comment: but this requires to handle it within the code, not? for example, if I change model and i dont want existing clients work is not interrupted, how can you handle this? in your case, you should keep 2 models in your new publish, 1 for old version 1 for new version?

Comment: @batmaci  One option might be to use Azure API Management to manage your version https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/apimanagement/2017/09/29/managing-versions-and-revisions-using-the-http-api/